I am trying to fetch all subcollection from different parent collections but it returns empty array
I am trying to fetch all subcollections named jobs from different customer collections. I tried to get it with collectionGroup which I understand is you can fetch any collections from different parent. When I try like this list return empty.
      class JobListViewModel : ObservableObject {

     @Published var jobs : [Job]? = nil     
 
       func loadJobs() async throws {
            Firestore.firestore().collectionGroup("jobs").getDocuments {
                snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
            print(error)
                      } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                self.jobs?.append(
         Job( 
              id: "\(document["id"])",
              position: "\(document["position"])",
              salary: "\(document["salary"])", 
              state: "\(document["state"])", 
              city: "\(document["city"])", 
              description: "\(document["description"])"))
            }
        }
    }
}
        VStack {
         List {
                ForEach(viewmodel.jobs ?? [Job(id: "", position: "", salary: "",                             state: "", city: "", description: "")] ) { job in
                    Text(job.city)
                    Text(job.position)
                }
            }
            
           }
           .onAppear {
            Task {
               try await viewmodel.loadJobs()
            }
        }


I have called documents as collection group  above but maybe I called wrong. that's what I m asking
